# Make dependency files path error after GCC update 7.2.1 to 10.2.1

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Im working on a C project that uses GNU 7.2.1 Compiler. I'm developing my project with Cygwin and on Windows 10.

There is a for-loop in my project that was written incorrectly:

```c
for (idx==0; idx<10; idx++)
```

With `gcc(arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe)` 7.2.1, I realize; this for-loop compiled successfully, there is no error produced. This for-loop's first parameters is wrong (`idx==0`); an error should have been produced.

I wanted to try new version of `gcc(arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe)` and make a decision if new version of `gcc(arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe)` is more reliable, maybe more performance. So, i tried it.

With `gcc(arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe)` 10.2.1, this for-loop cannot compile successfully; I get an error. I wanted it to be like this too.

After a while, I recompiled my project, but there are too many errors:

```
gmake: No rule to make target 'D\:/PROJECT/some_header.h', needed by '../BUILD_DIR/some_source.o'.
```

This error occurs because dependency files were created with incorrexct dependency paths. Paths should be like `D:/PROJECT/some_header.h`, not like `D\:/PROJECT/some_header.h`

I'm using these dependency flags: `-MMD -MF$(@:.o=.d) -MT$@`

I tried different combinations of these flags, but nothings changed.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: GNU is the name of the project; the C compiler `gcc` is one of many, many tools they produce.

Comment: try `make --always-make` (or `make -B`) to do a "clean" build

Comment: What actually is run by make to generate these files?  That is, what is the fully-expanded syntax for the `-MMD -MF$(@:.o=.d) -MT$@` flags you show here?

Comment: When i type gmake in console, Makefile compile each files like that:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MF$(@:.o=.d) -MT$@ -c $< -o $@`.

`$(CFLAGS)` is a little longer, only contains compiler options:
`-Wall -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -Werror=uninitialized -Werror=maybe-uninitialized -Werror=overflow -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mtune=cortex-a15 -mabi=aapcs -mapcs -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -mfloat-abi=hard -g -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fno-strict-overflow`